# CouchDB reduce bug when grouping?

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I have a map reduce query that aggregates values extracted from several documents into a single aggregated document that maps to the object structure of by client application.

My key on the outputs is a 2 element array with a dataset identifier and a dataset country segment.

When I run the reduce on 'exact' grouping this works reliably.

**The Problem:** As soon as I aggregate the data by the dataset identifier only ie. I use group level 1, some of the values are incorrect, most of the incorrect ones are doubled, but some of them have other values. Is there any known issue, or is this a bug with my code?

After running my map query, I have a set of values that looks like:

```
{ [type]: 
    { date: 
        { [metric]: [value], 
          [more metric value combinations] 
        }
    }
}
```

I have several documents and run a reduce that should join them so that I get the following structure:

```
{ type1: 
    { date: 
        { [metric]: [value], 
          [more metric value combinations] 
        }, 
      anotherdate: 
        { [metric]: [value], 
          [more metric value combinations] 
        },
    },
  type2: 
    { date: 
        { [metric]: [value], 
          [more metric value combinations] 
        }
    },
}
```

To achieve this I use the following reduce query:

```
function (keys, values) {
    //return values[0];
    var returndoc = values[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        //Merge the current and previous object
        returndoc = MergeDocs(returndoc, values[i]);
    }
    return returndoc;
}

function MergeDocs(doc1, doc2) {
    var types = ['Live', 'Benchmark'];
    for (var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
        var t = types[i];
        // if the source document does not Benchmark or Live column,
        // create it and add values from the other document. 
        if (!doc1[t] && doc2[t]) {
            doc1[t] = doc2[t];
        }
        // if the source document has a value and the other
        // document exists, sum values.
        else if (doc1[t] && doc2[t]) {
            doc1[t] = MergeReports(doc1[t], doc2[t]);
        }
    }
return doc1;
}

function MergeReports(report1, report2) {
    // iterate over the dates in the report in the report
    for (var date in report2) {
        // if there is no value for 
        if (!report1[date]) {
            report1[date] = report2[date];
        } else {
            for (var metric in report2[date]) {
                if (!report1[date][metric]) {
                    report1[date][metric] = report2[date][metric];
                } else {
                    report1[date][metric] = 
                        report1[date][metric] + report2[date][metric];
                }
            }
        }
}
return report1;
}
```

Comment: If I were you, I would try another path. Try to *map* data with a compound key (e.g. `[type, date, metric]`). What would be even better would be to change the order (e.g. [type, metric, date]), you could then reuse the same index with a group_level of 2 to get the all time maximum, minimum, average...

Comment: Aurelien, I like the idea and will test it. There's however still the issue for me, that the aggregates in the above method are correct whenever my group_level is exact, but they are incorrect (in what appears to be random occasions) whenever I set the group_level to aggregate by the country segment. So currently failing to find an error in my reduce code I don't know how I can trust the group levels.

Comment: I am not sure about what is your problem with countries, but, when you use compound keys, you can do amazing things with just playing with `group_level` and built-in reduce functions (like `_stats`).